# Make SwipeRefreshLayout under Toolbar in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, swiperefreshlayout, android-appbarlayout

I use `SwipeRefreshLayout` as the root element of my layout as I need to refresh *everything* on the screen. The layout is listed below:

```xml
<SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        <ViewPager />
        <AppBarLayout>
            <Toolbar />
            <FrameLayout>
                ...
            </FrameLayout>
        <TabLayout />
    </CoordinatorLayout>
</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When I swipe down on the layout, the refresh circle of `SwipeRefreshLayout` appears from the top of the screen, on top of `Toolbar`. So I use `SwipeRefreshLayout#setProgressViewOffset` to make the circle start from an offset of the toolbar's height, but when the refresh completes, the circle will hang oddly on the toolbar for a moment before disappearing: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhFRd.jpg)

How could I make the refresh circle under the toolbar?

Comment: what you want to do actually ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ just "make the refresh circle under the toolbar"

Comment: This layout is for activity or fragment ?

Comment: remove <NestedScrollView>

Comment: You want to refresh the content within your `FrameLayout`, as well as the content within your `ViewPager`? But you want the `SwipeRefreshLayout` indicator to appear on top of the content within the `FrameLayout`? Do you want to be able to pull down on the `FrameLayout` as well as the `ViewPager` to refresh both sets of content?

Comment: @Bryan Yes I want to trigger the refreshing by pulling down on both the `FrameLayout` and the `ViewPager`, and I want to refresh both of them too. What's worse combining a `SwipeRefreshLayout` with a `ViewPager` will cause conflicts on the swipe gestures. I think maybe I should find a better way for the refreshing.

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ You're right. The NestedScrollView should be put inside fragments of ViewPager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems as though you want to implement a [coplanar indicator](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/bdb4a0df199ff68e635187b1d7e11520df7f89f35d2663564a6306f6bd8a2a1f341dc97b0af0eabe29eba2c3062e7a8b4ed8b43081546c58fc26f774558e6490), as documented in the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-swipe-to-refresh.html#behavior-placement). To do this, you should use either the `setProgressViewEndTarget()` or the `setProgressViewOffset()` methods:

```
// This method will offset the end of the indicator animation
int target = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.indicator_end_target);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(true, target);

// This method allows you to set both the start and end values for the indicator animation
int start = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.indicator_start);
int end = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.indicator_end);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(true, start, end);
```

By setting the first parameter to `true` in each of these methods the indicator will animate its scale as it comes into view, instead of just getting clipped by the edge of the containing view.

Comment: This might be the best solution so far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm sure that "coplanar indicator" is a precision term, but I can't get over the fact that it sounds like something McFly would hook up to his flux capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toolbar` should be outside `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Do it as follows

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
            <FrameLayout>
                ...
            </FrameLayout>
        <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLayout>
    <SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <NestedScrollView>
            <ViewPager />
    </SwipeRefreshLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Then how should the AppBarLayout work properly without a Toolbar?

Comment: Thanks but that will make SwipeRefreshLayout totally below AppBarLayout, including both the Toolbar and other views in it. I just want to make the circle appear below Toolbar. That seems nearly impossible to me.

Comment: @BetaKuang what alternate you can do is use this hierarchy of layout views and in onRefresh() of SwipeRefreshLayout you can write code to refresh all the views.

Answer (score 0):

Were do you exactly want to show the circle? If you want to show it on the FrameLayout you should put swipeRefreshLayout above FrameLayout while not setting SwipeRefreshLayout as the root view.

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <ViewPager />
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
        <SwipeRefreshLayout>
           <FrameLayout>
              ...
           </FrameLayout>
        </SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <TabLayout />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This could work if the `FrameLayout` has a fixed height, as `SwipeRefreshLayout` will force the child view to match the entire size, so the height of `SwipeRefreshLayout` can't be set as `wrap_content`. Unfortunately in my case the height of `FrameLayout` is dynamic, so this solution will make the `FrameLayout` totally invisible.

Comment: can you specify on with view or views you want fire the refresh action?

Comment: On both FrameLayout and ViewPager.